# Hide second image with same class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide an image on my page and I cannot figure out how to do it. The image has the same class as another image that is display before it on the same page. I have tried these methods:

`jQuery('img.ui-datepicker-trigger').eq(1).hide();`

I have even tried to hide both of them to no avail:

`jQuery('img.ui-datepicker-trigger').hide();`

I have also tried adding a CSS class to hide them, via jQuery, no luck. If I alter the CSS in the plugin's styles and make the class `display: none`, it works. However, I just need to hide one of them.

Here is the site in question: http://new.teenchallenge.cc/donate/?donation_type=Student+Sponsorship
It is the second calendar icon next to the "Start Date" field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

I should have hidden the whole span as someone mentioned. I could not figure out how to hide the span so I started hiding the child elements, which was not a great idea. I should have just stuck with my first plan to hide the span.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // Prepopulate gravity forms fields
    jQuery('span.ginput_product_price_label').text('Monthly cost per student:');
    jQuery('#field_2_22 > label').text('Total recurring monthly support:');
    jQuery('span.gf1stpay_recurring_date').eq(1).hide(); //<----- THIS IS WHAT WORKS
    //jQuery('#gf1stpay_2_8_5').hide();
    //jQuery('.gf1stpay_end_date_label').hide();
    //jQuery('img.ui-datepicker-trigger').html('This is a test...');    
}
```

);

Comment: Can you post the actual code here?

Comment: Any relevant markup and code goes **in the question itself**, not on some random link. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: `jQuery(".ui-datepicker-trigger").hide()` works in chrome's console, on the page. You're probably trying to hide it before it's actually inserted into the DOM

Comment: You need to write the code when DOM is ready.

Comment: Also, you seem to be hiding the input that goes along with it, the one for the end date. Why not hide its parent instead ?

Comment: @PabloRincon Very good point. This was what I was going to do initially and could not figure it out so I started hiding child elements when what I should have done was stick with figuring out how to hide the parent span. Thanks for bringing this up! I am not sure that this was a clear answer, but it was the answer that I needed.